# Sql job schedule between given time frame

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, job-scheduling

I have a .sql job that I want to run once every day between 2PM to 5PM. How can I schedule this?

Comment: Voted for transfer to DBA site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Expand the SQL Server Agent node and right click the Jobs node in SQL Server Agent and select `'New Job'`

2.In the `'New Job'` window enter the name of the job and a description on the `'General'` tab.

3.Select `'Steps'` on the left hand side of the window and click `'New'` at the bottom.

4.In the `'Steps'` window enter a step name and select the database you want the query to run against.

5.Paste in the T-SQL command you want to run into the Command window and click 'OK'.

**6.Click on the `'Schedule'` menu on the left of the New Job window and enter the schedule information (e.g. daily and a   time).**

7.Click 'OK' - and that should be it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [SQL server agent](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189237.aspx).
This is a service that comes with SQL server, and can be configured via enterprise management studio to execute SQL jobs at preconfigured times